# why is a class is added when it is not told to jquery to do so

Tags: jquery

The following code is so simple... but it is causing some trouble to me:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
        <style type="text/css">
            .emphasis{
                color: #ff0000;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <ul>
            <li>hello</li>
            <li>hello 2</li>
            <li> hello3</li>
            <ul>    
                <li>this is another</li>
            </ul>   
        </ul>


<!-- from here we start the jquery code -->         
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $("ul").children("li:nth-child(1)").addClass("emphasis");
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

now the problem with this is that this code is adding `emphasis` class to first child of the first `ul` and at the same time it is adding class `emphasis` to second `ul`'s `li`
which i haven't told the jquery to do so

### The demo

the jsfiddle link is as follows:
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e5trq7bm/1/)

i could be wrong because i don't know jquery much and trying to improve it

thanks

Comment: `$("ul > li:first").addClass("emphasis");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector is pointed at all `<ul>` elements and then to their first child `<li>` element. You need to be more specific to choose only one. If you wanted to filter out any `<ul>` you could add another filter like this:

```js
$("ul").children("li:nth-child(1)").each(function() {
    var e = $(this);
    if(e.parents('ul').length == 1) {
        e.addClass("emphasis");
    }
});
```

```css
.emphasis{
    color: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li>hello</li>
    <li>hello 2</li>
    <li> hello3</li>
    <ul>    
        <li>this is another</li>
    </ul>   
</ul>
```

Comment: I expanded on my answer to give you a way to select only parent level `<ul>` elements without modifying your HTML, the correct way depends on what you are trying to accomplish and what you are willing to change.

Answer (score 1):

That is not valid html. You can't have `<ul>` as a child of `<ul>`. First change that.

After doing that you can do this

```
$('ul > li:first').addClass('emphasis');
```

`>` means direct child

Answer (score 1):

Your jQuery selector describes a pretty common relationship (li first child of ul). Add an ID to the first ul so you can select it specifically.

```
$('#myList > li:first-child').addClass('emphasis');
```